# Higher Speed or More RAM?

Tags: memory

Which is more important for gaming? More RAM, or a Higher Speed RAM?

I'm asking because I have 2 different brands of RAM and if I use both they'll get clocked to the lower speed for compatibility and I want to know whether I should go for more ram (20GB) or faster RAM (8gb).

The RAM speeds are 8gb of 1600Mhz and 833Mhz.

Comment: More ram or faster ram only going to help you if you multitask. You are better off getting a faster CPU or GPU for gaming.

Comment: I've got a seriously good GPU and CPU, I know that's the main bottleneck, I'm just wondering what effect, if any, RAM speeds actually have

Comment: Great! Well you have 8GB of RAM which will be enough for video gaming. In regards to your original question, I would say **faster RAM** would be more preferable than more RAM. 20 GB of RAM for a video game is just going overboard. But as I mentioned before, CPU and GPU are more important for gaming.

Comment: Well I do use photoshop and do some video rendering as well if that's of any consequence

Comment: @zain.ali - The frequency of memory is going to have little effect on the overall system performance unless you are talking 3x and 4x clock differences.  Author didn't even mention the clock of the memory, so its not clear, how much of a difference that it could make.

Comment: Have edited to add the speeds :)

Comment: @JamesHughes - Unless you are going to run a benchmark, your system performance will be nearly identical, using either frequency memory.  What will make a bigger difference is more memory, if you were talking 3000Mhz memory I might feel differently.

Comment: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/toms-ultimate-ram-speed-tests,review-30648.html

Comment: 20GB is a complete overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Higher speed RAM will probably provide more benefit in your situation, especially since the clock rate of your faster DIMMs is nearly double that of the lower speed DIMMs (1600MHz vs. 833MHz). Since you have a really good CPU and GPU, the memory is more likely to be a bottleneck in your system.

If you mix the DIMMs, you'll not only have a reduced clock rate, but probably also reduced timings (CAS Latency, etc.).

Overall it ends up being very application dependent. Here's an article on Tom's Hardware that covers the topic in more detail and with benchmarks:
http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/memory-bandwidth-latency-gaming,3409-10.html

Here's a relevant quote from their conclusion:

> Two out of five game tests, F1 2012 and The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim, showed us that that both bandwidth and latency can influence frame rates significantly. Both variables appear equally important, too. We might have guessed we'd see the results we did; after all, both titles are already known to be less graphics-bound than the others.
>
> On the other hand, Metro 2033, Battlefield 3, and Aliens vs. Predator demonstrated no changes at all. The performance of the first two titles is most consistently associated with the speed of a given machine's graphics subsystem, so it makes sense that we don't see a big impact from memory bandwidth or timings.

According to their findings, there is definitely a potential benefit (based on the application) to having faster memory.

What's left to determine is if the amount of memory is insufficient in your case and would benefit from an increase. Modern applications and games **generally** don't need more than 8GB system memory, so I assume your application performance won't go up with more memory. Application load time and system responsiveness may be a little better with more memory due to the effects of caching, but this is at the cost of better sustained application performance.

Overall I suspect using only the higher speed RAM is better in your case, but it's probably worth your time to run a few benchmarks in both configurations since you already have the RAM.